# Why can node not find a module? (Even when I'm not requiring it)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been trying to import a js file in the same folder using `require` but I keep getting this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'player'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/shaham/Code/Typersion/server/items.js:1:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

Here's the code:

```
// server.js
var Player = require("./player")

//player.js
A bunch of functions...
module.exports = {
    functionNames...
}
```

File architecture:

```
server/
-server.js
-player.js
```

I even get this error when trying to run `node player.js`

What am I doing wrong?

If you want a deeper look: here's the repo: https://github.com/ShahamNoorani/Typersion (you'll be looking for the `refactoring` branch).

Comment: what's your cwd when you're running this code? are you still getting this error when you run this code from the application root (that's where your package.json resides)?

Comment: @Roomy I've been running `npm start` from the root which runs `server.js` and I still get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to launch your code and there's my error message:

```
user@user ~/git/Typersion (git)-[refactoring] % npm start

> typersion@1.0.0 start /home/user/git/Typersion
> node server/server.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1023
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'player'
Require stack:
- /home/user/git/Typersion/server/items.js
- /home/user/git/Typersion/server/enemy.js
- /home/user/git/Typersion/server/server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1020:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:890:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1080:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/git/Typersion/server/items.js:1:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1196:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:929:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1080:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/user/git/Typersion/server/items.js',
    '/home/user/git/Typersion/server/enemy.js',
    '/home/user/git/Typersion/server/server.js'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! typersion@1.0.0 start: `node server/server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the typersion@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2020-05-06T21_25_55_323Z-debug.log
```

It clearly says that there is a problem in the `server/items.js` file, even the lineno and colno is specified, so basically by looking into that file I can tell you forgot to add `./` before your imprt.

TLDR

change `var Player = require("player")` to `var Player = require("./player")` in `server/items.js`

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much. I wonder why this didn't show up in my console or error logs...

Comment: maybe different output may be caused by different node version, mine is `v14.1.0`